# How to read Objects from ManyToMany Relation class in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database, manytomanyfield

I have made a class called friend where i want to connect users as followers. Here From this class i am unable to read the users those are following another user. For Eg if 'a' user fllows 'b' user. Then i want to get the names of user that followed b from the user id of b and display them as followers of a. This class is also not storing the userid of the following user and followed user. I am new to many to many relation field. Kindly help.

Code in Models.py

```
class Friend(models.Model):

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower', null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod

    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):

        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(

            current_user = current_user

        )

        friend.users.add(new_friend)
```

Its function in views.py is

```
def change_friends(request, operation, pk):

    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if operation == 'add':

        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)

    elif operation == 'remove':

        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)

    return redirect('home')
```

Its url in urls.py is

```
path('connect/<operation>/<pk>)',views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
```

Comment: The wording is slightly confusing. If user "a" adds user "b" as a friend is user "a" a friend of user "b" - is the relationship symmetrical?

Comment: no from this class a is only able to follow b

Comment: thus the relation is asymmetrical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your methods, you are not saving your modifications.

When you do `friend.make_friend(...)`, after that you should save your `friend` object: `friend.save()`, so `m2m` fields can be also saved.

Same goes for your other methods updating `users` fiels of a `Friend` object.

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? You are doing modifications to an object `friend`  (because your class method `make_friend` does `friend.users.add(new_friend)`), but you don't save those modifications brought to your `friend` object. After adding `new_friend` to `users`, you have to save your `friend` object if you want modifications to persist: `friend.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a friend model you can create a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) where you define the many to many relationship. If you define the `ManyToManyField` with `symmetrical=False` then it will not be symmetrical

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers')
```

You need to define this model as your user model in your settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'you_app.CustomUser'
```

Now you can use this relationship directly from the user instance itself

```
def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        request.user.friends.add(friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        request.user.friends.remove(friend)
    return redirect('home')
```

Now your `CustomUser` instances will have 2 relationships that can be queried

```
request.user.friends.all()
request.user.followers.all()
```